# If $\theta=\alpha+\beta$ such that $\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}=\frac{x}{y}$, then $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}\sin\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> If an angle $\theta$ is divided into two parts $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\beta}=\dfrac{x}{y}$, show that $\sin(\alpha - \beta)=\dfrac {x-y}{x+y}\sin\theta$.

I have done it in the following way:

[image]

Is there any other alternatives to this? If there is then please suggest.

Comment: So long on this site, and you prefer an **image** to $Latex$ ?

Comment: What alternative do you want? If I replace the ${\tan a\over \tan b} $ by $\cot b\over \cot a $, and proceed accordingly, will it be an **alternative**?

Comment: @  Qwerty, But I am expecting a completely different method of solution.

Comment: What you have done is possibly the simplest approach.